# C#-Where to use log4net setting with azure function app?

Tags: azure-application-insights, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender, azure-application-settings

I'am working with azure functions,in order to log exception details to application insight from Azure functions, I was logging messages by using TelemetryClient() object along with instrumentation key like below

**Example**:

```
 var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
 telemetryClient.InstrumentationKey = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"];
 appInsights.TrackEvent(message);
```

So, Now I want to use Log4Net for logging messages to application insight by azure function.

Found here some information
[Log4Net with Application Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800320/log4net-with-application-insights#)

> Where to do below setting in azure function in order to use log4net logs with applicable insight? As azure function  app does not have web.config file.
>
> Can I add custom config file and put below setting and use that?

```
  <configuration>
  <configSections>
       <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="aiAppender"/>
    </root>
    <appender name="aiAppender" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender.ApplicationInsightsAppender, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
<configuration>
```